# inno setup activating using a licence key file

Tags: inno-setup

i want some help if it is possibale? is there any way that instead of using a serial name that you can use a licence key file that could be a txt, DAT or BIN file that will continue you with the installation of your product.

there is a solution out there which is called: VMPKit for Inno Setup but is expensive.

Here's [a link](http://vmpkit.com/scr/demo-wxp.htm)!

i hope you guys can help me, thank you in advance my friends.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom wizard page, and call you own function to activate your app. It is an easy and simple, but (in my way) it also need to call your dll for app activation.

I'd lost some time when trying to create such "activation" setup page,  but quickly found that it is dead wasting my time. Currently I use VMProtect Ultimate with VMP web license manager, and use vmpkit for integrating it into my apps. Sorry for my apologizes for a commercial software, but I think it worth it.

Your Inno setup script with VMPKit will looks like this:

```
[Code]
var
    ChoiceUserGroupPage : TInputOptionWizardPage;
    ActivationType: Integer;
    VmpikAppIsActivatedFlag : Boolean;

var
  VMPIK_SERIAL_FORMAT: array of integer; // see function InitializeSerialFormat and InitializeWizard
  VMPIK_SERIAL_NUM_PARTS: integer; // = 10;

const

  VMPIK_SERIAL_NUM_PARTS_MAX = 16;

  VMPIK_ACTIVATE_CHOICE_ALLOW_SERIAL           = True; // Change to your own value
  VMPIK_ACTIVATE_CHOICE_ALLOW_LICENSE_KEY_FILE = True; // Change to your own value True
  VMPIK_ACTIVATE_CHOICE_ALLOW_TRIAL            = True;
  VMPIK_ACTIVATE_CHOICE_ALLOW_LATER            = True; // Change to your own value
  VMPIK_ACTIVATE_CHOICE_ALLOW_ALREADY          = True; // Change to your own value
  VMPIK_TRIAL_SERIAL_NUMBER = '{#TRIAL_SERIAL}'; //'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX'; // Change to your own value or keep empty if VMPIK_ACTIVATE_CHOICE_ALLOW_TRIAL = False
  VMPIK_ACTIVATION_LOG_ALLOW = True; // allow log activation process and /ACTIVATIONLOG command line switch
  VMPIK_ACTIVATION_LOG_FILENAME_PREFIX = 'clp_'; // prefix for activation log filename


var
  ActivateChoicePage: TInputOptionWizardPage;
  EnterSerialNumberPage: TWizardPage;
  ChoiceKeyFilePage: TInputFileWizardPage;

#include "select_grp_scrip.pas"
#include "activate_hlp_script.pas"


procedure InitializeSerialFormat(var fmt:Array of integer);
begin
    SetArrayLength(fmt,VMPIK_SERIAL_NUM_PARTS_MAX);

    VMPIK_SERIAL_NUM_PARTS := 4;
    fmt[0]  :=  4;  fmt[1]  :=  4;  fmt[2]  := 4;  fmt[3]  := 4;
    fmt[4]  :=  0;  fmt[5]  :=  0;  fmt[6]  := 0;  fmt[7]  := 0;
    fmt[8]  :=  0;  fmt[9]  :=  0;  fmt[10] := 0;  fmt[11] := 0;
    fmt[12] :=  0;  fmt[13] :=  0;  fmt[14] := 0;  fmt[15] := 0;

end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;

  if ((PageID=ChoiceUserGroupPage.ID) and ((gsSkipPage<>False) or WizardSilent() )) then
  begin
     TestUserGroupChoice(ChoiceUserGroupPage);
     Result := True;
     Exit;
  end;

  if (PageID=ActivateChoicePage.ID) then
    begin
      if (VMPIK_IsNeedToSkipChoiceActivationTypePage() = True) then Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;

  if (PageID = EnterSerialNumberPage.ID) then
    begin
      if (VMPIK_IsNeedToSkipSerialPage(ActivationType) = True) then Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;

  if (PageID = ChoiceKeyFilePage.ID) then
    begin
      if (VMPIK_IsNeedToSkipLicenseKeyFilePage(ActivationType) = True) then Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
end;


function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin

    Result := True;

    if (CurPageID=ChoiceUserGroupPage.ID) then
    begin
       TestUserGroupChoice(ChoiceUserGroupPage);
       Exit;
    end;

    if (CurPageID=ActivateChoicePage.ID) then
    begin
      ActivationType := VMPIK_GetActivationTypeCode(ActivateChoicePage);
    end;

    if ((CurPageID=ActivateChoicePage.ID) and ((ActivationType=AM_LATER) or (ActivationType=AM_ALREADY))) then
       begin
         Exit;
       end;

    if (((CurPageID=ActivateChoicePage.ID)    and (ActivationType=AM_TRIAL)) or
        ((CurPageID=ChoiceKeyFilePage.ID)     and (ActivationType=AM_LICFILE)) or
        ((CurPageID=EnterSerialNumberPage.ID) and (ActivationType=AM_SERIAL)) or
        ((CurPageID=wpReady) and (VmpikCommandLineSkipActivationPages<>False)) // silent activation runs immediately before install
       ) then
       begin
         Result := VMPIK_OnNextButtonClick_TryActivate( CurPageID
                                                      , VMPIK_ACF_SHARE64FOR32KEY
                                                      , 'Software\' + '{#APP_REG_KEY}'
                                                      , 'License'
                                                      , 'SerialNumber'
                                                      , 'Trial'
                                                      , 'http://vmpkit.com/'
                                                      , ChoiceKeyFilePage.Values[0]
                                                      );
         Exit;
       end;

end;


procedure InitializeWizard ();
var
    numParams : Integer;
    paramNo   : Integer;
    StrParamName: string;
    StrParamVal: string;
begin

    VmpikAppIsActivatedFlag := False;

    InitializeSerialFormat(VMPIK_SERIAL_FORMAT);

    ChoiceUserGroupPage   := CreateChoiceUserGroupPage(wpLicense);

    ActivateChoicePage    := VMPIK_CreateChoiceActivationPage(wpSelectTasks); // wpWelcome, wpInfoBefore
    EnterSerialNumberPage := VMPIK_CreateEnterSerialNumberPage(ActivateChoicePage.ID);
    ChoiceKeyFilePage     := VMPIK_CreateChoiceKeyFilePage(EnterSerialNumberPage.ID);

    GrpParseCommandLine( ChoiceUserGroupPage );
    VMPIK_ParseCommandLine( ActivateChoicePage, EnterSerialNumberPage );
end;
```

Script above shows the "select user" page - install for all or install only for current user, and then shows activation page.

Also, VMPKit Inno setup scripts supports very silent setups - you can set your serial number in command line for unattended setups.

I found that the VMPKit is a nice